# String evaluation function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python

Is there any built-in function in JavaScript like `eval` built-in function in Python?
notice: `eval` function take an equation as string and returns result. for example assume variable `x`  is 2, then `eval("2x+5")` returns 9.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: Yes. It's called `eval`. :-)

Comment: [ECMA-262 sec 15.1.2.1.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.1.1).

Comment: I don't know how everyone else is using eval, but I can't execute `var x = 2, result = eval('2x+5')`... Unless I'm reading too in to this question, there's no 1:1 match (_some_ modification needs to be done for the arithmetic to work)...

Comment: @BradChristie I think everyone is ignoring the fact that `2x` is not valid in JS; however, written `eval("2*x+5")` it does what OP is asking.

Comment: @Mathletics I haven't ignored that fact in my answer.

Comment: @VisioN my universe of "everyone" was all the comments, and the answers that weren't yours :)

Comment: @Mathletics Ah, that makes sense for sure `:D`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is `eval` function in JavaScript too.

Besides, the statement should be valid for evaluation, i.e. `eval("2*x+5")`.

You should also note, that using `eval` in JavaScript is not recommended. You can read about at [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21).

**REF:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: +1 just because MDN, explaining the arithmetic difference, and the much-necessary disclaimer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called eval, oddly enough.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Edit: the mozilla link from VisioN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) is better, since it explains why you shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval()` however you will need to convert any "human" math operators to ones understood by javascript.

```
var sum = "4x5";

eval(sum.replace("x", "*"));
```

**Update** didn't read the part about x being a variable! that does make it slightly more complicated depending on how complex the equations are.

Comment: `x` is a variable, not a multiplication sign.